# Error on time format change - GridDataView / VBnet

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am storing in SQL HH:mm:ss format ( time(2) ), and GridDataView shows it this way. I am trying to change it both with Properties window, or by code

```
DataGridView1.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
DataGridView1.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm"
```

Color changes nicely, but value is not visible - shows ExceptionError - Incorrect Input Format 
[DataGridView Default error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoiFo.png)

Comment: Don't store strings in your database, store DateTime objects.

Comment: If your SQL Server column is data type `time(2)` then you are not storing anything using "HH:mm:ss" format. That is for text only. SQL Server may display it that way but that's not how it's stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SQL Server data type should map to `TimeSpan` in .NET. "HH:mm" is a valid format specifier for `DateTime` but not for `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` didn't even support formatting before .NET 4.0 and, since then, you'd need to use "HH\:mm", escaping the delimiter. Read more about formatting `TimeSpan` values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Changing to classical Datetime object solved issue.